# How does Linux handle permissions of files created on a different machine?

Tags: permissions, ownership

As far I know, a file's ownership on Linux depends on the file's owner's UID.

What happens if a user in a different machine has the same UID as a user on the server and then the file is copied to the server? Who owns that file?

What happens if a user on a different machine has UID that **is not the same** as any user on the server and then the file is copied to the server? Who owns that file?

I have created few users and a group. Then copy pasted:

```
$ sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user1
$ sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user2
$ sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user3
$ sudo adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --no-create-home user4
$ sudo addgroup userstart
$ sudo gpasswd -M user1,user2,user3,user4 userstart
$ sudo chown :userstart /home/blueray/Desktop/Permissions
$ sudo runuser -u user1 -- cp /home/blueray/Desktop/Permissions/test.html /home/blueray/Desktop/Permissions/test-copy.html
$ ls -la /home/blueray/Desktop/Permissions
total 72
drwxrwxr-x 2 blueray userstart  4096 Feb  8 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 blueray blueray     4096 Feb  8 11:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1  user1     31017 Feb  8 11:57 test-copy.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 blueray blueray    31017 Feb  6 05:50 test.html
```

The user who copied the file seems to own the file. Is it always the case?

Comment: When you're talking about a "server", how does the client get the files from the remote machine? Is it NFS server? Are the files copied by `rsync`? `scp`? Do you just move a USB stick from one machine to the other? In your question you run local `cp`, which is different then getting a file created on a remote machine. Also, when you say "resembles", do you mean "identical"? I cannot think how UID could "resemble" another UID... Does 100 resemble 101? It's either the same UID or it isn't, though same UIDs can belong to different usernames on different machines and vice versa.

Comment: By UID resembling another UID, i meant for example, in my local machine a user has UId 1005. In server, a user has UID 1005. I was not talking about fuzzy matching the UID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a non-privileged user cannot create files with different ownership than his own UID, so when he copies a file, the new file in the destination will **always** be owned by the UID of the user who ran the cp command.

This only applies for the case that a non-privileged user (non-root) copies the files, and it does't matter if he copies them from a remote machine or from a local one, and who was the original owner of the file.

If some user copies a file to a **remote machine**, the file will belong to the UID of that user on the remote machine. For instance, let's say you have user `foo` that has UID 100 on machine A, and on machine B there's also a user `foo` but with UID 101. If user `foo` copies a file from machine A to machine B (and it doesn't matter who was the original owner of the file and what was the method of copying), it will be created on machine B under the same user, but with his UID on machine B - 101. And again, this doesn't apply to copies ran by root.

Comment: What about `rsync`, `scp` or extracting an archive file?

Comment: @blueray Same. I said that a user cannot **create** a file with different ownership, and when you copy a file, and it doesn't matter how and where, the destination is **always** a new file created by the copier, so it cannot have different ownership.